# groovy regex with adjacent matches

Tags: regex, groovy

How can I get the count of all instances of a regex?

This gives the expected result:

```
groovy> 'banana'.findAll(~/\wa/).size() 
Result: 3
```

but this gives the same:

```
groovy> 'banaana'.findAll(~/\wa/).size() 
Result: 3
```

How can I find all 'a's preceded by a letter, including another 'a'?

TIA

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using lookbehind will give you the right output. Because [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are zero length assertions. They do not consume characters in the string, but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

```
(?<=\w)a
```